# Как открывать конкретное окно в PyQT5 из разных окон приложения по кнопке с одним названием

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyside2, сигналы-слоты

Я знаю, как подключать кнопки к функциям, знаю, как открывать другое окно, нажатием на кнопку.

Мне хочется сделать следующее: 
Допустим есть главное окно и **`2`** дочерних. На 2-х дочерних есть кнопка с одним названием "Регистрация".

Так вот, мне бы хотелось, чтобы в коде **`1`** раз где-нибудь прописать открытие окна Регистрации, чтобы не прописывать в каждом окне и сократить таким образом код.

Возможно у меня не хватает знания синтаксиса, прошу, направьте меня.

**main.py**

```
class RegWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_RegWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.setupUi(self)

      self.NazadButton.clicked.connect(self.button_action)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super().__init__(parent)
      self.setupUi(self)
      self.RegWindow = None
      self.RegButton.clicked.connect(self.button_action)

   def button_action(self, Button):
      if self.RegButton.text() == "Регистрация":
         self.close()
         self.RegWindow = RegWindow()
         self.RegWindow.show()

def main():
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MainWindow()
   window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

**q1370469_MainWindow_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
      MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
      MainWindow.resize(634, 409)
      MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
      MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
      self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
      self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
      self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
      self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 611, 20))
      self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
      self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
      self.line.setObjectName("line")
      self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
      self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 50, 20, 331))
      self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
      self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
      self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
      self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
      self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -10, 631, 81))
      self.label_2.setAcceptDrops(False)
      self.label_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label_2.setLineWidth(1)
      self.label_2.setMidLineWidth(1)
      self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.MarkdownText)
      self.label_2.setScaledContents(False)
      self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
      self.label_2.setWordWrap(False)
      self.label_2.setIndent(-1)
      self.label_2.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
      self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
      self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
      self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 190, 361, 21))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(13)
      self.label.setFont(font)
      self.label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label.setObjectName("label")
      self.MainButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.MainButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 101, 31))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(11)
      self.MainButton.setFont(font)
      self.MainButton.setObjectName("MainButton")
      self.InfoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.InfoButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 101, 31))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(11)
      self.InfoButton.setFont(font)
      self.InfoButton.setObjectName("InfoButton")
      self.VhodButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.VhodButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 0, 81, 31))
      self.VhodButton.setObjectName("VhodButton")
      self.RegButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.RegButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 0, 81, 31))
      self.RegButton.setObjectName("RegButton")
      self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
      self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 264, 361, 20))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(9)
      self.label_3.setFont(font)
      self.label_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
      self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
      self.GlossaryListButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.GlossaryListButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 101, 61))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(11)
      self.GlossaryListButton.setFont(font)
      self.GlossaryListButton.setObjectName("GlossaryListButton")
      self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
      self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 214, 441, 51))
      self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
      self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
      self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
      self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
      self.SearchButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(13)
      self.SearchButton.setFont(font)
      self.SearchButton.setObjectName("SearchButton")
      self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.SearchButton)
      self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(14)
      self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
      self.lineEdit.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.lineEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.lineEdit.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.lineEdit.setCursorMoveStyle(QtCore.Qt.LogicalMoveStyle)
      self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
      self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
      self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
      self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 611, 21))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(12)
      self.label_4.setFont(font)
      self.label_4.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.label_4.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.label_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
      MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

      self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
      QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
      _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
      MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
      self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:36pt;\">Глоссарий</span></p></body></html>"))
      self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Поиск по слову или фразе</span></p></body></html>"))
      self.MainButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "На главную"))
      self.InfoButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Инфо"))
      self.VhodButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вход"))
      self.RegButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Регистрация"))
      self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
      self.GlossaryListButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список\n"
"глоссариев"))
      self.SearchButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Поиск"))
      self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Главная страница</p></body></html>"))


   if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
      ui = Ui_MainWindow()
      ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
      MainWindow.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1370469_RegWindow_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_RegWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
      MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
      MainWindow.resize(632, 411)
      self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
      self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
      self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
      self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 611, 20))
      self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
      self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
      self.line.setObjectName("line")
      self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
      self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 50, 20, 331))
      self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
      self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
      self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
      self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 230, 131, 31))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(10)
      self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
      self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
      self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
      self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 611, 81))
      self.label_2.setAcceptDrops(False)
      self.label_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label_2.setLineWidth(1)
      self.label_2.setMidLineWidth(1)
      self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.MarkdownText)
      self.label_2.setScaledContents(False)
      self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
      self.label_2.setWordWrap(False)
      self.label_2.setIndent(-1)
      self.label_2.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
      self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
      self.MainButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.MainButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 101, 31))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(11)
      self.MainButton.setFont(font)
      self.MainButton.setObjectName("MainButton")
      self.InfoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.InfoButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 101, 31))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(11)
      self.InfoButton.setFont(font)
      self.InfoButton.setObjectName("InfoButton")
      self.NazadButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.NazadButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 101, 31))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(11)
      self.NazadButton.setFont(font)
      self.NazadButton.setObjectName("NazadButton")
      self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
      self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 150, 119, 71))
      self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
      self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
      self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
      self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
      self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(12)
      self.label.setFont(font)
      self.label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label.setObjectName("label")
      self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
      self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(12)
      self.label_3.setFont(font)
      self.label_3.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.label_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.label_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
      self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
      self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(12)
      self.label_4.setFont(font)
      self.label_4.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.label_4.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.label_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
      self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
      self.layoutWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
      self.layoutWidget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 150, 251, 74))
      self.layoutWidget1.setObjectName("layoutWidget1")
      self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget1)
      self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
      self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
      self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget1)
      self.lineEdit.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.lineEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.lineEdit.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.lineEdit.setCursorMoveStyle(QtCore.Qt.LogicalMoveStyle)
      self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
      self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
      self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget1)
      self.lineEdit_2.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.lineEdit_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.lineEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.lineEdit_2.setCursorMoveStyle(QtCore.Qt.LogicalMoveStyle)
      self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
      self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
      self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget1)
      self.lineEdit_3.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.lineEdit_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.lineEdit_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.lineEdit_3.setCursorMoveStyle(QtCore.Qt.LogicalMoveStyle)
      self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
      self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
      self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
      self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 611, 21))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(12)
      self.label_5.setFont(font)
      self.label_5.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
      self.label_5.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
      self.label_5.setAutoFillBackground(False)
      self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
      self.GlossaryListButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
      self.GlossaryListButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 210, 101, 61))
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(11)
      self.GlossaryListButton.setFont(font)
      self.GlossaryListButton.setObjectName("GlossaryListButton")
      MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

      self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
      QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
      _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
      MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
      self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 
"Зарегистрироваться"))
      self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:36pt;\">Глоссарий</span></p></body></html>"))
      self.MainButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "На главную"))
      self.InfoButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Инфо"))
      self.NazadButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Назад"))
      self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"right\">Логин:</p></body></html>"))
      self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"right\">Пароль:</p></body></html>"))
      self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"right\">Повтор пароля:</p></body></html>"))
      self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Регистрация</p></body></html>"))
      self.GlossaryListButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список\n"
"глоссариев"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_RegWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Михаил, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который вы уже написали.

Comment: Михаил, отлично, добавьте пожалуйста классы `Ui_MainWindow`  и `Ui_RegWindow`

Comment: @S.Nick, Имеете ввиду дочерние окна, скомпилированные в .py файлы?

Comment: Михаил, да,  `.py` файлы, которые содержат  классы `Ui_MainWindow` и `Ui_RegWindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте, если будет что-то не понятное - спросите.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1370469_MainWindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from q1370469_RegWindow_ui import Ui_RegWindow


class RegWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_RegWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
# -       self.NazadButton.clicked.connect(self.button_action)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
      
# ???       self.RegWindow = None

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.RegButton.clicked.connect(self.button_action)

        self.regWindow = RegWindow()                                        # !!!
        # !!! эти две кнопки выполняют одни и теже действия, т.е. одна лищняя
        self.regWindow.MainButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda ch, widget=self.regWindow: self.go_nazadButton(widget))
        self.regWindow.NazadButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda ch, widget=self.regWindow: self.go_nazadButton(widget))

    def button_action(self):                                        # - , Button):
#        if self.RegButton.text() == "Регистрация":
#            self.close()
#            self.RegWindow = RegWindow()
#            self.RegWindow.show()
        
        self.regWindow.show()
        self.hide()

    def go_nazadButton(self, widget):
        self.show()
        widget.hide()        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: большое вам спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: @Михаил пожалуйста.